# WAMP server asking for authorization when accessing it through external IP

Tags: wamp

When I'm on my localhost machine I can access my WAMP projects through localhost/[project folder] or [ipv4 adres]/[project folder]. When I'm creating responsive websites I'd like to be able to look at them on my phone and to do this I just put my WAMP server online with the button "Put Online".

However, whenever try to access my site using my external IP I get asked to put in my username and password, I would either like to know where I can find my username and password, or better yet, how to disable this.

Thanks!
-David

Answer (score 0):

RE: *However, whenever try to access my site using my external IP I get asked to put in my username and password*

This is most likely because you are getting to your Routers Admin panel.

If you do not recognise this page as your routers admin panel login, that probably means you are not familiar with your router and how to administrate it.

First you need to learn how to use your Router and its admin features

Then you need to learn what Port Forwarding is and then how to do it on your router. [Have a look at](http://portforward.com/) they will probably have both a description of what Port Forwarding is and how to do it on your specific router.

Comment: I won't need to portforward anything since I only want to be able to look at my website on my lan. If I ever create a site that I want to be open to the web I'll buy webhosting and all that good stuff.

Comment: Well in that case dont use your WAN/External IP address. You are not going outside your network so just use the local ip address of the PC in your network that is running you web server, and of course the WiFi on the phone

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do a security risk and disable the user authentication in you r network settings. Right click on your network icon at the bottom right corner and click on "Open Network and Sharing Center". Click on Advance Sharing Setting and de-select password protected sharing

Comment: If it is just for home testing and no one is connected to your network then you should be ok and it won't be a security risk

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the authorization, unfortunatly.

Comment: When you say external ip you mean public ip right? Also your username would be the name shown on your sidemenu or go to 'C:\Users' and you'll see your username. The password yould be what you use to log into your computer

Comment: Yes, the one I copied from whatismyip.com

Comment: Oh wait!! that is wrong, that ip given is not your public ip. That is use by your ISP. You cannot log into your computer with that unless you know the username and password for your ISP's application they use to issue out internet services.

Comment: How would I then find out my public IP?

Comment: You'll have to contact your ISO and request it. If it is not free ( comes with your current service ), you will need to pay a little extra for that.

Comment: @CAllen Totally wrong I am afraid. If he is using his WAN IP address from his phone, then it is more likely that the signon he is seeing is the Routers Admin panel signon page. Signin on to that will ONLY let him access the admin panel for the router

Comment: That can be it as well. Thanks for the update. Becaise i tried it at work n got my router's sign in page. But to do stuff from outside your betwork requires a public ip addtess.